# How do you resize the box of a symbol, while vertically centering it?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, math-operators, scaling

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphics}
\def\myboxmin{\mathop{\raisebox{.15em}{\scalebox{.5}{$\boxminus$}}}}

\begin{document}
$A \myboxmin B$
\end{document}
```

I would like to make it better in two ways

1. Define a `\RescaleSymbol` command in such a way the above output is obtained typing `\RescaleSymbol[.5]{\boxminus}` (say, the default value for rescaling is `.75`)
2. Without the `\raisebox`, the rescaled symbol is aligned to the baseline. Now, it must take as values (half of) the height of the symbol to be rescaled.

How can I do?

Comment: Are you sure it should be `\mathop`? The use example suggests `\mathbin`.

Comment: Mh. Of course it depends on the kind of symbol you have to rescale...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define your new macro as: `\newcommand{\RescaleSymbol}[2][<default_optional>]{..}` with `#1` the optional parameter and `#2` the mandatory one. The default value for the first (optional) parameter is written in the second pair of brackets. Use the new command as `\RescaleSymbol[<scale>]{<symbol>}` or `\RescaleSymbol{<symbol>}` with the default scale of 0.75.

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphics}

\newcommand{\RescaleSymbol}[2][.75]{\mathop{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#1}{$#2$}}}}}

\begin{document}
$A - \RescaleSymbol[.5]{\boxminus} B$
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: For some reason `\vcenter` didn't work, but I guess the reason is I didn't enclose the rescaled symbol in a `\hbox` command. This seems to work fine, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You probably have `\mathop` to vertically center the symbol with respect to the formula axis, but this only works if the argument to `\mathop` is a single character.

The `amsmath` package has a built-in mechanism for deciding whether a symbol is a `\mathbin` or a `\mathrel`, which is used for `\underset` and `\overset`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rescalesymbol}[2][0.75]{%
  \binrel@{#2}% this makes \binrel@@ to mean \mathbin, \mathrel or empty
  \binrel@@{\rescale@symbol{#1}{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\rescale@symbol}[2]{%
  \mathpalette\rescale@@symbol{{#1}{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\rescale@@symbol}[2]{%
  \rescale@@@symbol#1#2%
}
\newcommand{\rescale@@@symbol}[3]{%
  % #1=math style, #2=scale factor, #3=symbol
  \vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#2}{$\m@th#1#3$}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A \rescalesymbol{\boxminus} B$

$\scriptstyle A \rescalesymbol{\boxminus} B$

$A \rescalesymbol[0.5]{\boxminus} B$

$\scriptstyle A \rescalesymbol[0.5]{\boxminus} B$

$A \rescalesymbol{\pitchfork} B$

$\scriptstyle A \rescalesymbol{\pitchfork} B$

$A \rescalesymbol[0.5]{\pitchfork} B$

$\scriptstyle A \rescalesymbol[0.5]{\pitchfork} B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to set the kind of the symbol differently from its standard status of `\mathbin` or `\mathrel`, or you need a totally different kind, I suggest a trailing optional argument:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\rescalesymbol}{O{0.75}mo}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}
   {%
    \binrel@{#2}% this makes \binrel@@ become \mathbin, \mathrel or empty
    \binrel@@{\rescale@symbol{#1}{#2}}%
   }
   {#3\binrel@@{\rescale@symbol{#1}{#2}}}%
}
\newcommand{\rescale@symbol}[2]{%
  \mathpalette\rescale@@symbol{{#1}{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\rescale@@symbol}[2]{%
  \rescale@@@symbol#1#2%
}
\newcommand{\rescale@@@symbol}[3]{%
  % #1=math style, #2=scale factor, #3=symbol
  \vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#2}{$\m@th#1#3$}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A \rescalesymbol{\boxminus} B$

$\scriptstyle A \rescalesymbol{\boxminus} B$

$A \rescalesymbol[0.5]{\boxminus} B$

$\scriptstyle A \rescalesymbol[0.5]{\boxminus} B$

$A \rescalesymbol{\pitchfork} B$

$\scriptstyle A \rescalesymbol{\pitchfork} B$

$A \rescalesymbol[0.5]{\pitchfork}[\mathop] B$

$\scriptstyle A \rescalesymbol[0.5]{\pitchfork}[\mathop] B$

\end{document}
```

[image]